# Principal Component Analysis, how many components?

Tags: machine-learning, pca

I don't understand one point of PCA. PCA returns the directions that maximizes the  variance for each feature? I mean, it will return a component for each feature of our original space, and only the `k` biggest components will be used as axis for the new subspace right? So actually if I'm in 50-D and 49 features have a strong variance i can just pass to a 49-D space? I'm speaking in plain English of course, nothing formally or technical.

Thanks

Comment: Yes but i mean, if we look at the Covariance Matrix algorithm, the number of eigenvectors and eigenvalues returned is N and only k of them are returned as final dimensions. What is that N? Should be the number of columns of our data matrix X ... so?    Edit: So in 2 dim are returned 2 components, as the number of features

Comment: the input features are analyzed using PCA to discover all the top orthogonal dynamics which are explicitly not a one to one mapping from the input features ... so your 50D input features may well get reduced to just 3 dimensions ... often none of the input features is purely just one of the PCA output dimensions ... think of a handful of pencils thrown onto the ground ... on the flat 2D surface you only have two possible dimensions so all those pencils sent into a PCA will result in just those two vectors represented by X and Y ... each PCA output is orthogonal - independent of others

Comment: Here is a confirm, there is one component for each feature but Pca permit to prioritize them using eigenvalues ! https://deeplearning4j.org/eigenvector#covariance

Comment: to really understand PCA I suggest you avoid just throwing your data into some library call ... instead roll up your sleeves and write your own PCA from scratch ... sure later when you are in production resort to using someone else's library but not during the learning stages ... the PCA algorithm is not magic and you can write your own in a few pages of code

Answer (score 7):

If your original data has 50 dimensions, then PCA will return 50 principal components. It is up to you to choose a subset `k` of those principal components that can explain the most variance, typically at least 90% of the variance. The PCA software you use will usually compute how much variance is explained by each principal component, so just add up the variance and select the top `k` that can get you to 90% of the total variance. See this [PCA tutorial](http://www.octoberraindrops.com/publications/Phan_2016_IntroductionToPCA.pdf):

> In general, we would like to choose the smallest K such that 0.85 to
>   0.99 (equivalently, 85% to 95%) of the total variance is explained, where these values follow from PCA best practices.
>
> ... When we say that PCA can reduce dimensionality, we mean that PCA
>   can compute principal components and the user can choose the smallest
>   number K of them that explain 0.95 of the variance. A subjectively
>   satisfactory result would be when K is small relative to the original
>   number of features D.

Comment: Many thanks. So the k components that i wil choose should explain the most variance of our total data right? I mean, taking the best k components ( in terms of variance) should give me a subspace where the variance of our new projected data is maximized ?

Comment: Each principal component explains a small amount of variance, and your software should return the principal components sorted by decreasing variance. So if you use the top principal component, then that `k`=1 principal component maximizes the variance for the subspace spanned by 1 PC. If you choose the first `k`, then those `k` PCs maximize the variance spanned by `k` PCs. That's because the PCs are returned in sorted decreasing order. You then need to pick the right `k` that reaches 90% of the total variance.

Comment: can you tell me about this?

Data sets are
M = Features = 700 and
N = Number of observations = 91
if I apply PCA then how many components it should formed?
Is it N components or M components?
I know the component with a maximum variance will be selected but before selecting how many component PCA create or make?

Comment: @Rabnawaz: Your PCA software should return as many principal components as there are features. So in your case, it should return M=700 principal components. It's up to you to select the top k of them.

Comment: but when I run it in R it should return a matrix of 91 X 91 rows. from them, I have to select the top k components from  them.

i am confused about its notations. @stackoverflowuser2010

Comment: @Rabnawaz: If you have a question about the R implementation of PCA, then you should ask a separate, specific question. Add the `r` tag.